# Regex to match string between two words, where the ending boundary word is optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match text between the words **called** and **with** but also still match even if *with* is missing.
e.g.

In this sentence, I want to match Mary Jane

> "Create a picklist called **Mary Jane** with the value ox."

Here I want still to match Mary Jane, even without a *with* clause afterwards

> Create a picklist **Mary Jane**.

My regex only matches when *with* is present, but not if it is absent.

```
"Create a picklist called Mary Jane with the value ox'".match(/called(.*)(?:with)/i) // Matches "Mary Jane"

"Create a picklist called Mary Jane'".match(/called(.*)(?:with)/i) // Error: Does not match anything
```

How can I write a regex that can match both cases?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/jTd1aw/1 `called(.*)(?:with|$)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that doesn't work for the first example

Comment: I am sorry, it should be like this `called(.*?)(?:with|$)` https://regex101.com/r/5RDHPS/1 And if you don't want to match the ending dot and the spaces, try it like this `\bcalled (.*?)(?: with|\.?$)` https://regex101.com/r/1ZNBOG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the name without the leading spaces and without the dot, you might use a capturing group with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
\bcalled (.*?)(?: with|\.?$)
```

- `\bcalled`  Match literally preceded with a word boundary
- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any char except a newline non greedy
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `with` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\.?$` Match an optional dot and assert end of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ZNBOG/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. This is what I came up with. I hope it helps.

```js
let str1 = "Create a text field called Mary Jane with ninja";

let str2 = "Create a text field called Mary Jane";

console.log(words(str1));
console.log(words(str2));

function words(str){


  let arr = str.split(" ");
  let i = arr.indexOf("called");
  let j  = arr.indexOf("with");
  if( j == -1){
    return arr.slice(i+1);
  }
  return arr.slice(i+1,j);
}
```